# jQuery in HTML onclick

Tags: jquery, dom

I have code that looks like this:

```
<?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($keyArray); $i++) {
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <th>
        <a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()">
        <?php echo $keyArray[$i] ?></a>
    </th>
    <input type="hidden" name="tableHeader" value="<?php echo $keyArray[$i]; ?>">
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

I'm trying to submit the form through a link.
To test the form, I use:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

I've tried using a button type submit, and it works. I don't know what's wrong with the jQuery in my onclick, but the info is not being sent.

Comment: Why don't you just do `onclick="this.form.submit()"`

Comment: Maybe the link is put somewhere else (outside the form) because you are generating invalid HTML. A `th` element cannot be the child of a `form` element.

Comment: My guess is that $(this).closest('form') is not fetching any form...

Comment: could always [`HTMLInputElement.form`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement), e.g. `onclick="this.form.submit()"`

Comment: I also tried giving an id to the form and it didn't work either. Basically what I want to do is sorting the table records when people click on a table header. If I have invalid HTML, what alternative could I be using?

Comment: this.form.submit() didn't work either.

Comment: Post the rendered HTML.

Comment: Change your <th> to <div> and give it an id.

Answer (score 1):

May be if you give an ID to your form and using it in your jQuery command :

```
<form id="form<?php echo $i ?>" action="" method="POST">
<th><a href="#" onclick="$('#form<?php echo $i ?>').submit()"><?php echo $keyArray[$i] ?></a></th>
<input type="hidden" name="tableHeader" value="<?php echo $keyArray[$i]; ?>">
</form>
```

Comment: @jSmith: If this works, then the problem really is your invalid HTML. Just fix the HTML and your code will work as well.

Comment: Right Felix. I'd chose you as best answer now because this simple modification makes it work. (Simply moving the `th`'s outside the form).

Answer (score 1):

Why you dont just add a submit button instead of an anchor with a jQuery trigger ?

```
<input type="submit" id="submit-btn" value="<?php echo $keyArray[$i] ?>">
```

If you want it like an anchor, you can use CSS :

```
#submit {
    background: transparent;
    color: blue;
}
```